# i have a camera shake script but when i click start it directy goes off and it wont stop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

i have a camera shake script but when i click start it directy goes off and it wont stop
in this script i wanted to trigger the shake effect

public class GameOver : MonoBehaviour
{

```
public Explosion shake;

void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D coll)
{
    Debug.Log("Collision!");
    if (coll.gameObject.tag == "platform")
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        shake.GameOver = true;
    }
}
```

}

and this is the other script

public class Explosion : MonoBehaviour
{

```
public Transform cameraTransform;
private Vector3 orignalCameraPos;

public float shakeDuration;
public float shakeAmount;

private bool canShake = false;
public bool GameOver = false;
private float _shakeTimer;


void Start()
{
    orignalCameraPos = cameraTransform.localPosition;
    GameOver = false;
    _shakeTimer = 0;
}

void Update()
{
    if (GameOver = true)
    {
        ShakeCamera();
    }
}

public void ShakeCamera()
{
    _shakeTimer = shakeDuration;
    StartCameraShakeEffect();
}

public void StartCameraShakeEffect()
{
    if (_shakeTimer > 0)
    {
        cameraTransform.localPosition = orignalCameraPos + Random.insideUnitSphere * shakeAmount;
        _shakeTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
    else
    {
        _shakeTimer = 0f;
        cameraTransform.position = orignalCameraPos;
        GameOver = false;
    }
}
```

}

if you are able to help me i would be very thankfull :)

Answer (score 2):

in the statement `if (GameOver = true)` you are setting GameOver to true and then checking its value. I think you might have wanted to use `if (GameOver == true)` or `if (GameOver)` which will check if this variable is set to true.